# Discord.js v13 error: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

**I'm working on a userinfo command in discord.js v13 and I don't know how to fix this error**

**ERROR:**

> **[Photo Error]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/71eWe.png**

> **if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
>
> RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: "serverinfo",
  description: 'Gives Info About A Server',

  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const { guild } = message
    const icon = message.guild.iconURL() // Icon Of Server
    const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.map(e => e.toString()) // Roles Of Server
    const emojis = message.guild.emojis.cache.map(e => e.toString()) // Emojis Of Server
    const emojicount = message.guild.emojis.cache
    const members = message.guild.members.cache // Members In Server
    const create = message.guild.createdAt.toLocaleDateString() // Server Create Date 

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setTitle('Server Info')
      .setThumbnail(`${icon}`)
      .addField('Server Onwer:-', guild.owner)
      .addField('Server ID:-', guild.id)
      .addField('Server Creation Date:-', create)
      .addField('Boost Count:-', guild.premiumSubscriptionCount)
      .addField('Boost Level:-', guild.premiumTier)
      // You Can Add Any Emoji
      .addField('Member Count:-', `${members.size}\n${members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}(Human)\n${members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}(BOT)`)
      .addField('Mmeber Stats:-', `${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'online').size}:-\n${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'idle').size}:-\n${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'dnd').size}:-\n${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'offline').size}:-⚫\n`)
      .addField('Highest Role:-', guild.roles.highest)
      .addField('Roles:-', `${roles}`, true) // <true> Means All Roles Will Come In Line
      .addField('Emoji Count:-', `${emojicount.size}\n${emojicount.filter(emoji => !emoji.animated).size}(Non Animated)\n${emojicount.filter(emoji => emoji.animated).size}(Animated)`)
      .addField('Emojis:-', `${emojis}`, true) // <true> Means All Emojis Will Come In Line // This Will All Emojis Of Server
      // You Can Add Any Emoji
      .addField('Server Stats:-', `${guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'text').size}⌨️\n${guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'voice').size}\n${guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'news').size}\n${guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'category').size}`)
      .setFooter('Server Info', icon)

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/71eWe.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you are trying to access the `owner` property in the guild. The `guild` variable does not have this property. If you want to fetch the owner, you can either get their id by using this:

```js
const ownerId = guild.ownerId
```

Or, if you want to fetch the owner's complete details, you can use this:

```js
const owner = await guild.fetchOwner()
```

I also noticed that you are trying to send numbers instead of strings in many places such as:

```js
.addField('Boost Count:-', guild.premiumSubscriptionCount)
.addField('Member Count:-', `${members.size}\n${members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}(Human)\n${members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}(BOT)`) // members.size is a number
.addField('Emoji Count:-', `${emojicount.size}\n${emojicount.filter(emoji => !emoji.animated).size}(Non Animated)\n${emojicount.filter(emoji => emoji.animated).size}(Animated)`) // emojicount.size is a number
```

and trying to send objects instead of strings like here =>

```js
.addField('Highest Role:-', guild.roles.highest)
```

(the [`highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=highest) property is an object which contains the complete role, you can access the name by using [`highest.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=name)). So in all these places, you can convert the numbers to strings by using template literals (by surrounding them with backticks `).